# Wordpress .htaccess rewrite for database template

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to convert a website to WordPress. The URLs in use are currently in the format:
http://www.domain.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html

To display items that are stored in the database, I have created a page template DatabaseFetch.php and have added a page to WordPress to use this template at address http://www.domain.com/database/ (this can also be access by http://www.domain.com/?p=39)

The template DatabaseFetch.php will have the PHP code to get the ID number from the URL and then use this ID number to get the relevant item details from the database.

I am trying to alter the .htaccess file found in the WordPress root folder as I want all URLs in the format of http://www.domain.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html to be processed by http://www.domain.com/database/ but I want the browser to display the URL in the format of http://www.domain.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html (ie the URL not to change)

I have tried many combinations over the last couple days but I cannot get it working. Using the line

```
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$  /database/ [NC,L]
```

brings up WordPress 404 page

Using the line

```
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$  /?p=39 [NC,L]
```

brings up correct page, but the URL in the browser changes to http://www.domain.com/database/

Does anyone know how I need to alter the .htaccess file below to get the desired results I seek?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$  /database/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$  /?p=39 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Update**
Maybe if I ask the question in another way. On a non-Wordpress installation, I have the desired outcome defined by one line in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$  database.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

How would I able to do the same in WordPress?

Comment: Have you tried getting WordPress to do what you need instead?  [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) might do what you need, without needing to change .htaccess (which would stop the URL changing)

Comment: No I haven't tried to get WordPress to do it as I am not familiar with WordPress but have edited the .htaccess file many times. Plus I thought it should be easy enough with .htaccess

Comment: define destination file in RewriteRule or remove L-flag and/or try N-flag

Comment: I have tried both lines with flags and no flags and combination of flags but nothing gets the desired result. I am not sure what you mean by "define destination file in RewriteRule"